# Asterisk do not terminate channel

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

I have problem Asterisk do not terminate channel when member goes UNREACHABLE or UNREGISTERED.

I have Queue and some member. Member answer incoming call from Queue.  If during the conversation member status would  beUNREACHABLE or UNREGISTERED Asterisk do not terminate channel. Channel terminated after hangups call.from caller.

**Note:** i have option

```
rtptimeout = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Peer status have no any relation to channel state

Asterisk should not terminate channel.

rtptimout option have no relation to peer state. It will stop call on no rtp for 10 sec. So likly you have rtp.

Comment: I understood that:
During the conversation peer status would be UNREACHABLE or UNREGISTERED rtp packet from peer side will be 0. And after 10 sec (rtptimeout = 10)Asterisk must terminate call.
What is wrong in this case?

Comment: No, that is not true. Peer will be UNREACHABLE when SIP packet not come in. RTP can still go. Asterisk should not terminate call. If you want change that, you always can rewrite chan_sip or chan_pjsip.